# How to generate buy sell trading signals using ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, trading

I have made a ggplot with my data set having close price and two sets of limits(upper limt 1=ucl1,lower limit 1=lcl1,upper limit 2= ucl2, lower limit 2=lcl2) using following commands

```
date=seq(as.Date('2000-1-3'),length.out=6486,by=1)
ggplot(mrfdata,aes(x=date))+geom_line(aes(y=ucl2),colour="blue")+geom_line(aes(y=lcl2),colour="blue")+geom_line(aes(y=close),colour="red")+geom_line(aes(y=ucl1),colour="green")+geom_line(aes(y=lcl1),colour="green")+ggtitle("7 days") +  xlab("ma of 7 days") + ylab("standard deviation")
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("zoom", height = "350px"),
  plotOutput("overall", height = "150px",
             brush =  brushOpts(id = "brush", direction = "x")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  mrfdata=data.frame(date=date,ucl2=ucl2,ucl1=ucl1,close=close,lcl1=lcl1,lcl2=lcl2) 


  p <- ggplot(mrfdata,aes(x=date))+geom_line(aes(y=ucl2),colour="blue")+geom_line(aes(y=lcl2),colour="blue")+geom_line(aes(y=close),colour="red")+geom_line(aes(y=ucl1),colour="green")+geom_line(aes(y=lcl1),colour="green")+ggtitle("7 days") +  xlab("ma of 7 days") + ylab("standard deviation")


  output$zoom <- renderPlot({
    if (!is.null(input$brush)) {
      p <- p +xlim(as.Date("1970-01-01") + input$brush$xmin, as.Date("1970-01-01") + input$brush$xmax)
    }
    p
  })

  output$overall <- renderPlot(p)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now I need to generate buy and sell trading signals using this gg plot.
Buy signal whenever close price intersects lcl1 and ucl2.
Sell signal whenever close price intersects ucl1 and lcl2.
I have done a lot of research but as I am new to R, not able to apply commands.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Question is unclear, why did you add shiny part to the code?

Comment: @PoGibas so that ggplot is mlore clear and to add zoom in function

Comment: you don't really need the charts. you just have to use two consecutive rows for comparison and create the signal

Comment: @SatZ How??????

Answer (score 0):

We do not know how you define the limits. You could do this:

```
mrfdata$Buy=ifelse(mrfdata$close>mrfdata$lcl1 & mrfdata$close<mrfdata$ucl2 ,1,0)
mrfdata$Sell=ifelse(mrfdata$close<mrfdata$ucl1 & mrfdata$close>mrfdata$lcl2,-1,0)
```

Maybe you will get more robust signals including the comparison of close with moving average (MAv):

```
mrfdata$Buy1=ifelse(mrfdata$close>mrfdata$lcl1 & mrfdata$close<mrfdata$ucl2 & mrfdata$close>mrfdata$MAv,1,0)
mrfdata$Sell1=ifelse(mrfdata$close<mrfdata$ucl1 & mrfdata$close>mrfdata$lcl2& mrfdata$close<mrfdata$MAv,-1,0)
```

For Buys you will get:

[image]

#### UPDATE

To find the intersections you can define a function and then put the signals together.

```
interspoints=function(v1orig,v1ref,datav=NULL){
  above <- v1orig>v1ref
  crossp <- diff(above)!=0
  inters.pts <- which(crossp)
  list(crosp=crossp,dfbp=data.frame(datav=datav[inters.pts],intpts=inters.pts,v1orig=v1orig[inters.pts]))
}
###
#Buy signal whenever close price intersects lcl1 and ucl2.

interspoints(mrfdata$close,mrfdata$lcl1,mrfdata$date)

interspoints(mrfdata$close,mrfdata$ucl2,mrfdata$date)
```

Comment: we need to create buy sell signals when close price intersects with its limits (not when its greater or less than its limits) or we can say to generate buy sell signals when close price=limits according to graph.

Comment: limits are computed using standard deviation and 7 day moving average (ma ± sd) and (ma ± sd/3)